# Where are Chrome URLs stored?

Tags: google-chrome

I just came across [chrome://chrome-urls/](http://chrome://chrome-urls/) and was wondering where are the pages and JavaScript stored. I could access the URLs without an internet connection, so i am guessing it is stored locally.

I could not find them in the application folder and local appdata folder. In that case, where are they stored?

Answer (score 0):

They are hard-coded in. I decided to explore the contents of Chromium.app on Mac and found a whole bunch of resources inside a framework file.